# Pull down to refresh in table-view in iphone doubts

Tags: iphone, pull-to-refresh

I am creating a bible application. There are lots of chapters in the bible (e.g. genesis, exodus etc).

I created a button for each chapter loading. I load the verses and chapter in table-view cell. When the button is tapped it loads the next chapter and vise versa. I put the button in the footer of the table-view, but I want to change this functionality with pull down to refresh. I know pull down to refresh is used in many applications like Facebook and Twitter. I've also implemented this in my previous applications, but my need is to change the chapter when the user pulls down the table. When pulled down it changes to the next chapter.

I saw this functionality in the pocket-sword bible application; pull up for next chapter and pull down for previous chapter. How can I implement this in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While that would work fine. I don't think it's the ideal implementation for navigation.

- How would you go back to the previous chapter?
- How would users know to pull down to go to the next chapter?

It just sounds and feels wrong.

I feel it would be better to implement swiping left and right to jump to the next page/chapter or even next/back buttons in either a navigation bar or toolbar. This is fairly standard.

Another option is to replicate the iBooks interface for jumping to chapters using the "paging bar" at the bottom (not sure what the correct name for it it)

Comment: swiping left and right?but ben i am using tableview for displaying verses.is it possible to do it in a tableview?can you expalin with a sample code?please.thank you.

Comment: Yes it's still possible with a table view. Although I think I'd go with next/previous chapter buttons. Are you loading each verse into each row in the table view? Or are you loading a small snippet and then the user has to tap on the row to see more?

Comment: i loded each verse to each row.

Answer (score 0):

we have to put same code thAT IS  what code we used for directing next chapter in button-click,that code have to be put inside the _(void)refresh method.It automatically redirected to the next page when we pull down the table-view.What ever functionality we can add to this function.Thanks.